# How do you design a database schema for a user profile page

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

Trying to set up a user profile page for a job site. The database I plan to use is the MySQL database.

Looking into a few database design I came up with this schema.

First, the user management tables

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(96) NOT NULL,
  `mobile_number` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `address_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ip` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `approved` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `registration_date` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `user_address` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(128) NOT NULL
  `work_city` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `postal_code` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `user_description` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and then the education table and work experience

```
CREATE TABLE `education_detail` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `certificate_degree_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `major` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `institute_university_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `completion_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00'
)

CREATE TABLE `experience_detail` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_current_job` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `end_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `job_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `job_location_city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `job_location_state` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `job_location_country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `job_description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Note that user_id in table *user_address, user_description, education_detail* and *experience_detail* is a foreign key referencing it to the table user.

There are a few more table like skills, certification etc to which I plan on using user_id as a FK.

My question, is this database design good enough? Can you suggest me what should be done more to make the design much better?

*Keep in mind not all will have work experience, some may be freshers.*

Comment: Why is description in its own table? I can see, that a user can have multiple addresses, degrees and previous jobs, so putting that in extra tables makes sense (a lot of). But for description I don't think it's necessary (though not strictly wrong). I'd rather consider to have separate tables for e-mail and phone numbers, as these can be more that one per user too.

Comment: @stickybit, I chose to have a different table for description because there are lazy users out there and I believe not many would want to describe themselves. I am trying to have no column empty on my database. Maybe I am wrong and this is why I ask for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use InnoDB, not MyISAM.  (There are *many* Q&A explaining 'why'.)

`NULL` or an empty string is perfectly fine for a missing `description`.  Do you have any further argument for disliking such?  (Meanwhile, InnoDB is more efficient at handling optional big strings.)

Every table should have a `PRIMARY KEY`; you don't seem to have any.  The first table probably needs `user_id` as the PK.  Read about `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

As with `description`, why is `address` in a separate table?

May I suggest this for country name/code/id:

```
country_code CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET ascii
```

Education is 1:many from users, so `user_id` cannot be the PK.  Ditto for jobs.

Comment: Hi, I was scribbling and putting up a database to see how it should look like. My local MySQL is a mess and the engine is set to MyISAM. I do not intend to use MyISAM but InnoDB. Thank you for pointing out though. About the description, as stated I did not want an empty cell but this as you say is fine so I plan on not having a different table for the description (about me). Thinking about address in a different table too hardly makes any sense until the user have more than one postal address, thank you for the point out. user_id in education is supposed to be the FK not PK.

Comment: @DakshB - If a user can have more than one address, then the Address table needs to be separate and have a `user_id` in it.  This way, the relationship will be 1:many (1 user to many addresses).